# Attempting to delete executable shows error that the file is in use by that same executable

Tags: windows, notepad++, c++, recycle-bin, avg-antivirus

I've been doing some C++ programming in Notepad++ and, seemingly randomly, updates to the code did not modify the output, so I opened it up in Windows' file explorer to delete the executable, however upon attempting to delete BigFloat.exe, it shows [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh27l.png) (directory included in image).

In task manager, the app does not seem to appear. In terms of the actual code, I ran it and it worked fine and then commented out the main function, which caused this to happen so it's unlikely that the actual code which did this.

I tried disabling antivirus since it may have had some issue with new executables or something, but to no avail.

Last time this happened, I attempted to restart but, if I remember correctly, I had to turn of the computer with the button. (This solved the problem of course, but is hardly ideal.)

Comment: This behavior is caused by a specific feature of Visual Studio that you have enabled.  [Vhosts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774187/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-vshost-exe-file).  If you are not using VS to compile your software then your project has a bug

Comment: @Ramhound .. he isn't using visual studio, he is using gcc.  You can tell by the .gch file (gcc precompiled header).  So Doot.. I can totally help you figure this out but this isn't the place.  The best place to do this is stackoverflow and post your code.  You have an open file handle.  Either you did it.. or it has to do with how you are launching/debugging it.. It is possible you are using GDB to debug it and IT still has and open handle to the file?